# не устанавливается pip для python3.4 на debian 10

Tags: python, ssl, pip, openssl

Мне нужна версия python3.4. Его поставил из исходников. Но при установке не поставился pip.

> WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.

Попытка поставить через get-pip.py выдает тоже самое. 
В системе openssl установлен:

> Reading state information... Done openssl is already the newest
>   version (1.1.1d-0+deb10u2).
>       0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

Импорт модуля ssl в python3.4 выдает:

```html
>>>import ssl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stdin", line 1, in [module]
  File &quot;/home/makarosha/.python34/lib/python3.4/ssl.py&quot;, line 97, in [module]
    import _ssl             # if we can&apos;t import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: No module named "_ssl"
```

Хотя в питоне по умолчанию (3.7) все прекрасно работает.

Думал обойтись без pip и использовать для установки пакетов **poetry**. Так эта зараза тоже не хочет работать с моим python3.4. При попытке установить пакет выдает:

> [ImportError]
>   No module named 'pkg_resources'

Для моей версии python3.7 poetry прекрасно работает.

Как заставить работать pip в python3.4? Как получить для него ssl?

Comment: мб попробовать Anaconda?

Comment: что это значит?

Comment: ну пакетных менеджеров несколько, попробуйте Anaconda вместо pip

Comment: @finally Anaconda использует pip

Comment: Раз нет `_ssl.so`, 3.4 собрался с ошибками и хоть `make install` и проходит, но установка изначально будет каличная. Смотри логи `make`, там сто процентов есть ошибки в конце лога. Все остальное - это ошибки от отсутствия модуля.